# Inverse Kinematics for a 2DOF planar robot

Tags: python, inverse-kinematics

I have a simple 2DOF planar robot with this configuration:
[image]
L1 and L2 are the lengths of my 2 arms. L1 is 245.5mm and L2 is 160mm.
Alpha is the first angle (the one of the base) and beta is the second angle attached to the first arm.

When I programmed an Arduino and tried my math, I just got inconsistent results. The points were just completely off. Even linear motion along one axis didn't work. So I wrote a simple python script with the exact same math, where I keep x or y constant and increase the other one in small increments. Then I plotted a graph of the alpha and beta angle which were calculated. I would expect them to increase or decrease linearly (approximately like the dashed lines). But instead I get these results:
[image]

I am using the standard formulas which can be found all over the internet ([Source to original](https://robotacademy.net.au/lesson/inverse-kinematics-for-a-2-joint-robot-arm-using-geometry/)), but clearly they don't work. Here are they:

$\beta = cos^{-1}(\frac{x^2+y^2-L_{1}^2-L_{2}^2}{2*L_{1}*L_2})$

$\alpha = tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-tan^{-1}(\frac{L_2*sin(\beta)}{L_1+L_2*cos(\beta)})$

Also here is my Python code with which I do the calculations:

```
import math

L1 = 245.5
L2 = 160

x = 100
y = 70

def calc_IK_beta(x, y):
    beta = (x * x + y * y - L1 * L1 - L2 * L2) / (2 * L1 * L2)
    beta = math.acos(beta)

    beta_d = beta * 180 / math.pi

    if x < 0 and y > 0:
        beta_d = -beta_d
    elif x < 0 and y < 0:
        beta_d = -180 - beta_d
    elif x > 0 and y < 0:
        beta_d = -beta_d

    return beta #in radians

def calc_IK_alpha(x, y):
    beta = calc_IK_beta(x, y)

    alpha = math.atan2(y, x) - math.atan2(L2 * math.sin(beta), L1 + L2 * math.cos(beta))

    alpha_d = alpha * 180 / math.pi

    if x < 0 and y > 0:
        alpha_d = -alpha_d
    elif x < 0 and y < 0:
        alpha_d = -180 - alpha_d
    elif x > 0 and y < 0:
        alpha_d = 180 - alpha_d

    return alpha #in radians
```